# Wrong styles.css path after live reload

Tags: css, angular, sass, reload

I have a little (maybe big) problem with an angular application when hot reload hits

First time the application loads the correct resources with the correct path are loaded :

```
http://localhost:4200/styles.css
http://localhost:4200/styles.js
....
```

When I edit a component say for example '**VoiceComponent**' and the current link is http://localhost:4200/voices/
the application will reload but the resources loaded are

```
http://localhost:4200/voices/styles.css
http://localhost:4200/styles.js
....
```

Same thing if I edit a  '**HelloComponent**' and the current link is http://localhost:4200/hello/
the application will relaod but yhe resources loaded are

```
http://localhost:4200/hello/styles.css
http://localhost:4200/styles.js
....
```

The application tries to load **styles.css** in relative to the current path

angular.json:

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "nobleui-angular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/.htaccess"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/scss/style.scss"
              
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "nobleui-angular:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "nobleui-angular:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "nobleui-angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "nobleui-angular:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "nobleui-angular:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "nobleui-angular",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem :

I didn't close the `<head>` tag in index.html .. so the `<base href="/">` inside wasn't working

Comment: I just ran into the same problem, this solved it! Thanks

Comment: This should be upvoted umpteen times !! Without <head>, <base> tag doesn't work !! thanks for helping